# How to deal with over-long navigation bar titles?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar, title, titlebar

In my iPhone app, my navigation bar titles were often too long for the page, causing them to truncate (I usually have a button either side of the title, so space is limited). I therefore created my own title labels with a hard-coded font size so the text would shrink accordingly. However, I now realise that this wont neccesarily look right when other languages are chosen.

What is the normal practice for this? Do people just accept a truncated title, or reduce the font size accordingly (for English), or enforce a very short title that will be short enough in all languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a magic solution here. You just need to pick shorter titles or accept the truncation. You can always put the full text in the display rather than in the title bar if necessary.

Based on feedback from some users, I wouldn't go down the route of using smaller text. (I'm basing this on a toolbar at the bottom of the screen rather than the title bar, but the same principle applies.)

Comment: This is interesting. I'm surprised I haven't stumbled over a discussion about this as I thought it would be a common issue. Is truncation common? Don't people find it really ugly and annoying?

Comment: Most people just choose shorter titles. Look at all the Apple apps on your iPhone. How many of those use titles that require truncation?

Comment: @Stephen Quite a lot actually, e.g. Safari bookmarks, iPod app, even settings (at least in my language), where the titles are always the same.

Comment: The common element here is that they're displaying user entered data (long bookmark folder names, long album names). I don't see anywhere where Apple include a fixed title that requires truncation. Also, note that they truncate rather than use smaller text sizes.

Comment: With the language set to German, I also see a lot of truncation in the settings app, which does not show user entered data. However, I agree with you on the text sizes. When it truncates, it is usually still obvious what the text means.

Comment: I have decided to shorten all of my English titles so they fit. If they are truncated when the language changes, then so be it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I chose one title that is short enough for every language and display it regardless of what the view controller shows.

Apple shows as a title what the view controller shows: in the iPod app, for instance, when you select a playlist, the whole name is displayed. If it is too long, it gets truncated.

So I think it is ok to show a truncated title. You should not however make the text smaller as it will get too hard to read.

Comment: Mmm. Some good thoughts there. But what if I simply can't shorten my title enough, and therefore it will always be truncated on that page (in English at least). On some of my pages, I may have very few characters to play with when there is a long back button on the left and another button on the right.

Comment: You could always set the title to an empty string and show the info somewhere in the view controller. You might also want to look the [`prompt`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html) property, depending on your needs. It is usually used for displaying help though.

Answer (score 1):

Thought it would be relevant to contribute to this discussion with a great solutoin that I came across in one of the apps I've been using.

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/bookmyshow-movie-event-play/id405894842?mt=8

These guys animate the title left and right within the titleview's bounds, if the title text is too long. Looks neat and elegant without truncation, smaller text or other hassles.